# Android fragment Autocomplete text view does not executes setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, autocomplete

I have a fragment tab layout. Within the first tab fragment I have couple of autocomplete text views. These autocomplete text views bring in data async way. My problem is the very first autocomplete text view does not fires the set setOnItemClickListener callback while the other two autocomplete just work fine.
I tried moving single autocomplete from onCreateView to onViewCreated.
I removed the text watchers and tried as well but nothing has worked so far.

```
toEditAutocompleteText = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toEditAutocompleteText );
toEditAutocompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(onBranchSelected);
toEditAutocompleteText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                /*if (globalPreventTextWatcher == true) {
                    return;
                }*/

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (s.toString().length() >= 1 && toEditText.hasFocus()) {
                    //
                    // System.out.println("branch----------------------->"+s.toString());
                    searchBranch(s.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Just like the above autocomplete text I have one more autocompletetext. These both work fine however there is one just like this which does not triggers the callback.
The only difference between these three is the async function to fetch data call is different as in they return different array of objects.

One of the tab that has autocomplete text view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_update_delivery_record"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow>
                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/docketNumberEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:hint="docket number"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip" />

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tbl_txt2"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/red"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/white"-->
                <!--android:padding="10dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_margin="4dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                <!--android:text="Column 2" />-->

                <!--&lt;!&ndash; Column 3 &ndash;&gt;-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tbl_txt3"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="0dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/red"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/white"-->
                <!--android:padding="10dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_margin="4dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                <!--android:text="Column 3" />-->
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fromValue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="From Branch"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/consignor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Consignor"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/consignee"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/consignee"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Consignee"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/bookingLocation"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/bookingLocation"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Booking location"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/toEditText"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </TableRow>


            <TableRow>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/toEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="To City"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/invoice"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/invoice"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"


                    android:layout_margin="10dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Invoice"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/weight"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/weight"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"


                    android:layout_margin="10dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Weight"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"


                    android:layout_margin="10dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Quantity"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/invoice"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/truckNumberAutocomplete"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Truck number"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/invoice"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/modeSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="Mode"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/clearInput"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:padding="35dip"
                    android:layout_margin="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_layout"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/print"
                    android:padding="35dip"
                    android:layout_margin="35dp"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_layout"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_print_icon" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:padding="35dip"
                    android:layout_margin="35dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_button_layout"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
                    android:id="@+id/fabButton"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Main fragment holder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/toolbar"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"-->
        <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
        <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />-->

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Already spent couple of hours on this. There are no errors to reports. The autocomplete works fine for data fetch part however one autocomplete does not triggers on item selected callback when you select someting from the list.

Also this particular autocomplete text watcher also does not gets triggered but the async callback function is called.
Which confuses me futher.

Can anyone point towards what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. Apparently There are two other autocomplete text view in my code. These autocomplete were supposed to populate values via an api. API returned no data and they were not getting populated. Also these very autocomplete had an hasFocus listener on. The moment the top two autocomplete were populated my code started to work as is. It seems that the hasFocus on the top two autocomplete was messing up the third autocomplete.
So if you come across issue please check if you have focus listener applied on any element. If yes remove it and you are sorted.